# Add boolean in checkbox value

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Hi how to add if checkbox is check in input value true and when checkbox is uncheck false?

I try like this but it dosen't work:

```
$('#analytics').change(function(){
    if($("#analytics").prop('checked')){
        $("#analytics").val('true');
        console.log(analytics);
    }else{
        $("#analytics").val('false');
        console.log(analytics);
    }
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/edinpuzic/p88vhyb6/4/)

Comment: you are already adding it, just didn't include `jquery` in fiddle

Comment: I believe if you do it that way, the result would be a string of 'true' or 'false', see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

```
$('#analytics').change(function(){
        if($("#analytics").prop('checked')){
            $("#analytics").attr('value', 'true');
            console.log(analytics);
        }else{
            $("#analytics").attr('value', 'false');
            console.log(analytics);
        }
    });
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p88vhyb6/2/)

To add jQuery to a JSFiddle click the gear wheel in the top right corner of the JavaScript window.  See the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: You must add jquery to the jsFiddle javascript configuration or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of the quotes`''` wrapped around `true` and `false` values. Quotes `''` are for strings, not booleans.

See [**Article**](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp)

See [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/henceer2/)

Try this:

`var bool1 = Boolean('false');` the value should be true.

`var bool2 = Boolean(false);` the value should be false.

**Snippet**

```js
var bool1 = Boolean('false'); //the value should be true.

var bool2 = Boolean(false); //the value should be false.

var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');
var out2 = document.getElementById('out2');

out1.innerHTML = bool1;
out2.innerHTML = bool2;
```

```html
<label>bool1 =</label>
<output id="out1"></output>
<br/>
<label>bool2 =</label>
<output id="out2"></output>
<br/>
```

```
$('#analytics').change(function() {
  if ($("#analytics").prop('checked')) {
    $("#analytics").val(true);
    console.log(analytics);
  } else {
    $("#analytics").val(false);
    console.log(analytics);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set prop with the same function you get it:

```js
$('#analytics').change(function() {

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $(this).prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }

    console.log($(this).prop('checked'));
});
```